# OnClick table td variable not read in Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm having a trouble, why in my console didn't reflect the other td values `title` and `date`, it only reflects the `id` of my table. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

[image]

*table tbody*

```
<tbody>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% for folder in folder_list %}
<tr>
    <td> <a href="#" data-role="updategalleryss" data-id="{{ folder.id }}"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i></a></td>
    <td data-target="title">{{folder.title}}</td>
    <td data-target="date_upload">{{folder.date_upload}}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

*script*

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=updategalleryss]', function(){

   var id = $(this).data('id');
   var title = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=title]').text();
   var dateto = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=date_upload]').text();

   console.log(id) #it only read this
   console.log(title)
   console.log(dateto)
});
```

Comment: Hi , did below answer works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById(id).querySelector('td[data-taget="title"]').innerText
```

or

```
$("#"+id).find("td[data-taget=title]").text()
```

you can get title of td

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).parent("td").siblings()` to get datas from other tds where `a` tag is clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=updategalleryss]', function() {

  var id = $(this).data('id');
  //use this ->parent td -> siblings
  var title = $(this).parent("td").siblings('td[data-target=title]').text();
  var dateto = $(this).parent("td").siblings('td[data-target=date_upload]').text();

  console.log(id)
  console.log(title)
  console.log(dateto)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td> <a href="#" data-role="updategalleryss" data-id="1"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg">edit</i></a></td>
      <td data-target="title">somthing</td>
      <td data-target="date_upload">ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <a href="#" data-role="updategalleryss" data-id="2"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg">edit</i></a></td>
      <td data-target="title">somthing2</td>
      <td data-target="date_upload">ok2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <a href="#" data-role="updategalleryss" data-id="3"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg">edit</i></a></td>
      <td data-target="title">somthing3</td>
      <td data-target="date_upload">ok3</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```